# C# How to track down a font disposal

Tags: c#, resource-disposal

I have a font which is being disposed of which is causing an exception and I can't find where the font is being disposed.  I have a feeling it is being disposed of by print preview.  Can someone recommend how to track this issue down?

Thanks.

Comment: You could solve it (or at least find something out) by not using Print Preview.

Comment: Possibly use a trial version of one of the commercial memory profilers?

Answer (score 5):

You could try to set a breakpoint in `Font.Dispose`:

[Configuring Visual Studio to Debug .NET Framework Source Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx)

I'm not sure if the particular source code for the `Font` class is included, but you could give it a try.

Comment: The point where the exception is thrown is probably very different from where the font is disposed.

Comment: It sounds to me like the exception thrown isn't providing insight as to when/who was responsible for disposing the font in the first place.